# pandas float output format? (pd.to_csv)

Tags: python, pandas, format

I have a DataFrame with some float numbers, i.e.:

```
Date    Value
Sep-1   1.2
Sep-2   2.34
Sep-3   10.453
```

I hope if I could write the DataFrame to a text file with following format:

```
Date    Value
Sep-1   0001.200
Sep-2   0002.340
Sep-3   0010.453
```

I tried float_foramt='%4.3f' but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
df.Value.apply(lambda x : "{0:.3f}".format(x)).str.pad(8,side='left', fillchar='0')
Out[333]: 
0    0001.200
1    0002.340
2    0010.453
Name: Value, dtype: object
```

Comment: Your answer inspired me. I could apply this function to those columns. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ArthurYang if this is what you need would you like accept it?

Comment: sure. StackOverflow just doesn't allow me to accept an answer too early so I often accept it some days later. Sorry about the delay.

Answer (score 0):

The function can simply be:

```
str('{:0>8.3f}'.format(x))
```

The format method is very powerful for this.